# Replacing single image on click jquery/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

I'm working on a project and have run into a css problem. I have a survey, where once a user clicks on a certain option the grey image changes to compliment the correct choice.

I have it working, however, the images are in a class called `img-element`

So, once an image is clicked it changes all the images on the page with this class instead of just the one selected survey questions.

I've tried to solve this by adding a class for each question `.question1, .question2`:

#### survey.scss

```
           .questionnaire {
                    margin-top: 70px;
                    .question1 {
                        .box-title-with-image {
                            .img-element {
                                left: 95%;
                                top: -100%;
                                bottom: auto;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .question2 {
                        .box-title-with-image {
                            .img-element {
                                left: 95%;
                                top: -100%;
                                bottom: auto;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and in jquery, I've added multiple classes as shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_classes.asp
and implemented it in my .js file

### survey.js

```
        if (question1Answers.answer1) { // if user select answer1 of question1, then
            $('.question1, .img-element').attr('src','../images/img1.png');

                             // ...omitted code ...
  
        } else if (question1Answers.answer2 && question2Answers.answer2) {
            $('.question2, .img-element').attr('src','../images/img2.png');

}
```

However, it still has the same problem. I know this can be done with pseudo-classes in css, but I can't use that in this project. Is there another way around this using jquery?

Comment: You are coupling a question id's or key's with a class. This is a verry bad practice. Imagine you have 20 questions... you must declare 20 class... you must have for each question an id or a attribute like "id" or "data-question-number", this id must be present on particular divs, or img, or button... in your onclick method you must retrieve a id or key for the question (search in the button, or the parent div of this button).  Then search the img to be activated, like : $('img[data-question-number='99']).attr(....)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add src attribute to an img element of class "img-element" which is inside an element of class "question1 or question2" then your selectors should be like

this:

```
$('.question1 .img-element').attr('src','../images/img1.png');
```

and not this:

```
$('.question1, .img-element').attr('src','../images/img1.png');
```

using a comma will select all elements that have those classes.